# Retrieve single-post by AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a slider with images and link, from a custom post type. But I need to show the single post on pop-up. I am trying to do this for a while but I can't figure out what I am missing.

This is my: single-post.php

```
<?php
function my_load_ajax_content () {

$pid = intval($_POST['post_id']);
$the_query  = new WP_Query(array('p' => $pid));
$post = get_page($pid);
var_dump($pid.'asdsadda');
if ($the_query->have_posts()):?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();?>
        <?php var_dump($post);?>

        <p><?php $post -> the_title();?></p>   

    <?php endwhile;?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php
wp_reset_postdata();
echo '<div id="postdata">'.$data.'</div>';
}
?>
```

And Here js:

```
jQuery('.link-container a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var postid = $(this).attr('data-id'),
    ajaxurl = window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host+'/wp-content/themes/rory-dev/single-ontheroad.php';
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        action: 'my_load_ajax_content',
        postid: postid,
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT: if I add get_header() I got this error: Call to undefined function get_header() 
EDIT2: I guess this is due to my ajax script, is this prossible?

Comment: Is the get_header() call in the PHP or JS?

Comment: I can't figure out how ajax.php should look like.